# Wordpress Mobile Menu Plugin

Tags: wordpress, mobile, plugins, menu

https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-menu/
the plugin I am using
But my problem, Plugin search link;
mywebsite.com/?s=searchtitle

but what I want;
mywebsite.com/?s=searchtitle&post_type=product

I think it might be relevant code section;

```
$header_search  = '<a href="#" class="mobmenu-search"><i class="mob-icon-search-6 mob-search-button"></i><i class="mob-icon-cancel mob-search-cancel-button"></i></a>';
            $header_search .= '<div class="mobmenu-search-holder"><form class="mob-menu-search-form" action="" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="s" class="mob-menu-search-field" placeholder="' . $titan->getOption( 'placeholder_text' ) . '" autofocus="">' . $search_button . '</form></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm author of WP Mobile Menu. You can achieve this in several ways.
Try the solution in this topic.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223576/changing-a-themes-search-function-to-only-show-results-from-woocommerce